# How do I create a regex that optionally matches a set of characters, but ignores numbers?

Tags: r, regex

Consider the vector below:

```
v <- c("Q7", "Q7a", "Q7_", "Q75")
```

I need a regular expression that matches the first three elements, but not the fourth. In other words, I need a regular expression where the set [a-zA-Z_] is *optional* but numbers *are not*. I've attempted the following, but none subset only the first three elements:

```
grep("Q7[^[0-9]]", v)
grep("Q7[^[0-9]]?", v)
grep("Q7([^[0-9]])?", v)
grep("Q7[_a-zA-Z]?[^0-9]", v)
grep("Q7$?[^0-9]", v)
```

Comment: Try `grep("^Q7(\\D|$)", v)` if you want to match strings starting with `Q7` and then having no digit. Or `grep("^Q7[A-Za-z_]*$", v)`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! That did the trick.

Comment: Your third attempt just [lacks a `$` end](https://regex101.com/r/SggTEb/1) it seems :)

Comment: It's not clear what set of characters is acceptable after `Q7`, can it be explain better ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
> grep("^Q7[A-Za-z_]*$", v)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Here, `^Q7[A-Za-z_]*$` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `Q7` - a `Q7` substring
- `[A-Za-z_]*` - 0+ ASCII letters or `_`
- `$`  - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/emR2E3/1).

Alternatively, you may use

```
> grep("^Q7(?:\\D|$)", v)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Here, `(?:\\D|$)` matches either a non-digit (with `\D`) or (`|`) the end of string (`$`).

See  [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/emR2E3/2).

Comment: an alternative for the second regex `^Q7(?:\D)?$`

Comment: @lagripe Or even  `grep("^Q7(?!\\d)", v, perl=TRUE)`